# .NET Core API logging output on multiple lines

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working with an API running on .NET Core 3.1 and using the framework's default logging which works great for me. I was wondering if I can change the format of the output logs, though, because each individual log output prints 2 lines.

For example, the following line of code:

```
logger.LogInformation("'{0} {1}'. Status: {2}. Time: {3}ms.",
  context.Request.Method, context.Request.Path, context.Response.StatusCode, responseTime);
```

Produces the following output:

> info: MyApi.Utilities.RequestLoggerMiddleware[0]
> 'GET /api/users/current'. Status: 200. Time: 8ms.

Is there some way I can get `info: MyApi.Utilities.RequestLoggerMiddleware[0]` to print on the same line as the message text?

Comment: Use Write() instead of WriteLine().

Comment: @jdweng I'm using an `ILogger<T>` for logging, not the `Console` class. I have updated my question with example code.

Comment: go into the implementation of LogInformation as that is where its being done, if there is no override then you need to roll ur own.

Comment: Try Trim() : context.Request.Method.Trim()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by adding this code after `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` in `Program.cs` and configuring a console logger with the `Systemd` format:

```
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole(configure =>
                {
                    configure.Format = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLoggerFormat.Systemd;
                });
            })
```

The output now looks like this:

> <6>MyApi.Utilities.RequestLoggerMiddleware[0] 'GET /api/users/current'. Status: 200. Time: 8ms.

Comment: "Format is obsolete, please use FormatterName" it says